# How to change data type of Elastic search element

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to Elastic search. I have indexes which have array of objects. In order to get data related to single object only I need to set data type as nested.

How to set the data type of existing index element as nested?

Thanks.

Comment: If the field is already created with object type, then you cannot change it to nested, you need to delete your index and recreate it with the proper nested mapping.

Comment: Hi Val, Thanks for response. Is there any wrong impact of updating data type to "nested" ?

Comment: Updating an existing field type is [simply not allowed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings). Try it and you'll see an HTTP 400

Comment: Thanks for the link. If I create new index with mentioning one field as nested. Then will it impact in any way, like i cannot perform some query on kibana or elastic search?

Comment: If your field is nested then you have to use [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to query that field